# How to use one instance of MongoClient in java application server

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee

According to [mongodb java concurrency driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/) we can use one instance of `MongoClient` for multiple threads for example inside application servers. The only way I know to do this is to create `MongoClient` in static block:

```
static {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
}
```

the problem is I can't catch `MongoException` and return some helpfull information to user. So how to share a single instance of `MongoClient` between multiple threads inside Java EE application servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Create a service class and initiate the mongo connection lazily on first request, showing an error when you fail
2. Add a try catch and remember the error statically (I really don't like this one! But better than failing on exception in static context)
3. Use spring to initialize mongo (my preferred option)

Comment: first option means to use DAO class?

Comment: no, it means you have a class which acts as a service, exposing a singleton instance which does the connection in the back end and throws an exception if the connection failed.  Just means you don't access the mongo instance directly but let some "service" handle it.